# How to print multiple values from for loop inside print statement in a single line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

My Code has something like:

`user = input("Enter username: ")`

I have 10 variables like:

```
ch1 = "String1"
ch2 = "String2"
ch3 = "String3"
ch4 = "String4"
...
```

Suppose username entered is Pawan my input statement returns me a list:

```
basic_choices = input("Enter All your choices separated by ',' to perform in your remote system together: ").strip().split(',')
```

The output is some random numbers from 1 to 10 in a list:

`['1','3','7']`

Now I want to print a single string in a single line based on the choices of user:

For 1,3,7 is should give the output:

```
The strings selected by you are String1; String3; String7; in the strings list of Pawan
```

(semicolon should be included)
I have tried many ways but it doesn't work, either returns the value of only 1st number or it returns the generator object at address

```
print("The strings selected by you are ch{0}; in the strings list of {1}".format(*basic_choices, user))
print("The strings selected by you are ch{0}; in the strings list of {1}".format(choice, user) for choice in basic choices)</p>
```

Comment: You should look at casting the input strings like `"1"` to an integer, and then using that to index your list (e.g. 1 -> items[0] -> "String1").  You will want to put `ch1, ch2, ...` into a list to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would make sense to just put your "Strings" in a dictionary, where the keys are the possible user inputs.  I then used `str.join` to format the output correctly:

```
user = 'Pawan'

ch1 = "String1"
ch2 = "String2"
ch3 = "String3"
ch4 = "String4"
ch5 = "String5"
str_options = {'1':ch1,'2':ch2,'3':ch3,'4':ch4,'5':ch5}

basic_choices = input("Enter All your choices separated by ',' to perform in your remote system together: ").strip().split(',')

chosen = [str_options[i] for i in basic_choices]

print("The strings selected by you are " + 
      "; ".join(chosen) + 
      "; in the strings list of {}".format(user))
```

Note that (as is) this will raise an error if the user input is not in the dicitionary.